# Firefox add-on: Display a pop-up while hovering over an highlighted text on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm new around here, but I'm eager to learn and develop new things. As most of you guys are already pro`, I would love to be assisted if someone has time.

Here is the deal. I've started to play a bit with the Firefox Add-On SDK, and I want to develop a specific add-on / Firefox extension.

Case 1:

- I want to develop an add-on that creates a new icon in the toolbar (This is not a big deal.)
- I want to develop an add-on that highlights on a page some specific text (This will variable according to the domain) and when hovering it, to display a small pop-up with different info about the specific text.

Case 2:

- I want to develop an add-on that creates a new icon in the toolbar (This is not a big deal.)
- I want to develop an add-on that implements a new context element (a new option when right clicking) to search info about the selected text and display it by the same pop-up referred in Case 1.

Do you think that at least 1 of these 2 cases can be developed using Firefox Add-On SDK using modules as context-menu, widget, panel? I'm asking these because after looking over those modules I've seen some different results than the ones that I was expected.

While waiting for some tips I'm gonna try harder to get it done. :)

Thank you very much and I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

Kind regards,
Marius

Comment: Please assk individual, focused questions on SO, this sort of 'i need advice on a list of things' is generally frowned on and actually reduces the likelihood of people wanting to answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to develop an add-on that creates a new icon in the toolbar (This is not a big deal.)

[See the `ui` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui) in particular `ActionButton`.

> I want to develop an add-on that highlights on a page some specific text (This will variable according to the domain) and when hovering it, to display a small pop-up with different info about the specific text.

Read up on [Content Scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts).

In a content script, you'd then use DOM manipulation to insert highlights. SO has a bunch of question on how to find text in a DOM node or how to do popups in HTML.

You can use jQuery in content scripts, if you like (although I personally prefer not to... Why take the performance penalty of loading a library to deal with cross-browser compatibility issues when you're not developing cross-browser?)

> I want to develop an add-on that implements a new context element (a new option when right clicking) to search info about the selected text and display it by the same pop-up referred in Case 1.

Use the [`context-menu` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu) to add new menu items, and the DOM manipulation.